How can I dynamically call a function from a Python module?
I have a Python script where I want to dynamically load a module and call a specific function from it. For example:

The module file is my_module.py.
The function I want to call is my_function.

How can I load the module at runtime and call my_function without directly importing it at the top of the script?
Here's what I've tried so far:
import importlib

module_name = "my_module"
module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
result = module.my_function()
print(result)

Is this the right way to do it? What's the best way to handle errors if the module or function doesn't exist?

"What’s the best way to..."  is opinion-based and not on topic here. Sound like a XY question anyway... [ask] and [mre]

Why are you trying to do this dynamically? How much information do you have when writing your program, and how much information needs to be determined at runtime? Do you already know the module is called my_module, and the function is called my_function? Do you know what arguments the function takes?

It kind of sounds like you might not need a dynamic import - it sounds like you might really just need error handling.

I would do it like this:
import importlib

module_name = "my_module"
function_name = "my_function"

try:
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    result = getattr(module, function_name)

except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print(f"Module {module_name} doesn't exist")
    # Do something about it

except AttributeError:
    print(f"Function {function_name} doesn't exist in {module_name}")
    # Do something about it

else: # in case of no error
    print(result)

This way, you can clearly handle the non existing module or function, and having them defined previously in your code. Obviously, you may want to perform additional actions for each type of error.
As kindly noted by @deceze, at that point you have no idea whether result is a function or not, it is just a variable defined in the module. To make sure you are dealing with a function (or at least a callable) you can add another check afterwards:
else: # in case of no error
    if not callable(result):
        raise ValueError("{function_name} of type {type(result)} is not callable ")


FWIW, you're accessing the function, but you're not calling it.

@deceze You're totally right, at that point the code snippet I provided does not verify whether or not the attribute "my_function" is callable, I just stuck to the provided code from the asker. I am going to add this precision. Thank you for noticing
